# Opening a new screen from xml file text

Tags: android, xml, tabs, screen, new-operator

Hey all I'm looking to edit my app so that when a text within an `xml` file is selected, a new window opens. I've found various ways of making a new screen open via a class, but I need it done from a `xml` file.  My program as a `tablayout`, and here is some of the stuff displayed within my first tab:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView   
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="First Header here"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="First body text here"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Second header here"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Second body text here"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
            <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Third header here"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Third body text here"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

So basically I need it so that when a text is selected, a new screen pops up.  As said the reason this specifically has to be done in `xml` is because this is all apart of a tab layout, It would be great if the next within each tab could open a a new screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to get it to open an entire new layout outside of the tab view?

in which case all you need to do is set up a new xml file and on clicking the text call setContentView this will call upon the other xml file and open that page.

Or are you saying that on clicking it you wanna open another one of the tabs?

in which case your just looking to use a tab layout and tab widget:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

I'm just a bit confused as to what exactly your looking to do

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes to the first part. So in my above code example, if the user presses on "First header here" or anything else in a <TextView />, then I want that to open an entirely new screen.

Comment: Ok, so what your going to do is set up the screen you want to open as a separate xml file. then in your java file set up a OnClickLister for the Text View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
in this OnClickListener you want to call the setContentView for the other xml file. This will open the other page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't possible without code. Unless you write your own textview component that had the code you need written in it. I.e you have to do this with code somewhere. You can specify custom properties that specify where you navigate to.